# How to modify this Javascript to open links in a different window?

Tags: javascript, html, regex, parsing, hyperlink

This Javascript that I found [here](http://www.simonwhatley.co.uk/parsing-twitter-usernames-hashtags-and-urls-with-javascript) adds a method parseURL() to the string object so that if there are any links inside it will surround them with  tags so that they become clickable.

```
String.prototype.parseURL = function() {
    return this.replace(/[A-Za-z]+:\/\/[A-Za-z0-9-_]+\.[A-Za-z0-9-_:%&~\?\/.=]+/g, function(url) {
        return url.link(url);
    });
};
```

First of all, how does this even work? I know a little about regex expressions and can make simple ones, but I don't even see the word "href" in here!

How can this be modified so that the link opens in another window? i.e. How can I add the `target="_blank"` property in here?

Comment: I dont know about the first part of the post but to open a link in a new window you can use the following code: window.open(url, '', 'width=1024,height=768,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes'); You just have to go and find out about all the other parameters, there is quite a couple of them.

Comment: @jacqijvv: No, if you read carefully you'll see that this is all part of a process of generating markup -- *"...it will surround them with tags so that they become clickable"*. Actually opening the link will happen later when the link is clicked. Hence the OP's comment about the `target` attribute and his/her surprise that they don't see an `href` anywhere...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_link.asp
The String.link() method returns a text "blah" as a HTML link

```
<a  href='blah'>blah</a>".
```

So my guess is you have 2 solutions:

1/ override the link() definition (not recommended), declaring something like:

```
String.prototype.link = function(url) {
    return "<a target='_blank' href='"+url+"'>"+url+"</a>";
}
```

2/ define another function and use it instead of link() in the definition of parseURL():

```
String.prototype.blankLink = function(url) {
    return "<a target='_blank' href='"+url+"'>"+url+"</a>";
}
```

Then your code should become:

```
String.prototype.parseURL = function() {
return this.replace(/[A-Za-z]+:\/\/[A-Za-z0-9-_]+\.[A-Za-z0-9-_:%&~\?\/.=]+/g, function(url) {
        return url.blankLink(url);
    });
};
```

To explain a bit, replace() returns the input string where parts matching the regular expression (which in this case expresses the shape of any URL) are replaced by the second argument (the unnamed function that returns url.link()). What the JS reference doesn't say is that if you give a function - instead of a string - as the second argument of replace(), then replace() will provide the currently matching part as an argument to that unnamed argument-function. Sweet mechanics, assuming this works on any browser ;)

Answer (score 3):

> First of all, how does this even work?

<s>Apparently, elsewhere in the code you'll find this:</s>

```
String.prototype.link = function(url) { /* ... */ };
```

...which will end by returning a string. What the `replace` is doing is calling the anonymous function passed into it with the string that matched the regular expression as the argument; `replace` expects that function to return the appropriate replacement, which it then inserts in the string. (This second form of `replace`, which accepts a function rather than a string as the second argument, is quite useful but not as well-known as you might expect.) The anonymous function is calling the `link` function on the argument (`url`), which is a string, and returning the result. Hence my belief that you'll find a `link` function being added to the `String.prototype` somewhere in the code.

At least some browsers add a bunch of non-standard methods to `String` instances that wrap the string in tags; [`link`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/link) is one of those. It just returns the markup of an `a` element using the given URL.

> How can this be modified so that the link opens in another window?

<s>Actually the answer to the first question answers the second: Presumably you'll find the markup within that `link` function; you can update it there.</s>

Just replace the use of the non-standard `link` function with your own string concatenation:

```
return '<a href="' + url + '">' + url + '</a>';
```

Normally I'd say you should be sure to encode HTML entities, but as you're *already* dealing with an HTML source string, presumably they should already be correctly encoded.

Comment: Where did you find String.prototype.link? I didn't find it on that page.

Comment: Actually the `String.prototype.link` function already exists. Just like `String.prototype.blink` and `String.prototype.bold`.

Comment: @javascriptninja: My initial assumption was wrong; I'd forgotten about the non-standard 1995-era string extensions (`link`, `strong`, etc.). Updated.

Comment: it looks like its a native function. Try:  "Example".link('http://www.example.com');

Comment: @david: You must have been looking at a stale page. After ninja's comment above, a bell went off in my head saying "What, you don't remember 1995?" ;-)

Comment: @papirtiger: Yes, I think you must have been looking at a stale copy of the page, I updated a couple of minutes before your comment.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder My comment was totally posted 2 minutes before your edit :D but good to see you've changed it!

Comment: @david: Odd, I wonder if it took the latter of two collapsed edits. Well, if not, **I** was looking at a stale copy of the page!

Answer (score 2):

The 'href' is coming from the line `url.link(url);`

String.prototype.link is a silly function, included for backwards compatibility with silly code like this. It is silly and you should stop using it.

If you want to see what it's doing just `alert('something'.link('anotherthing'));`

It's like String.prototype.blink. Silly.